# Find if column contains value from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns.
Column E extends up to 99504 (values) and column I extends to 2691 (values).
Both columns contains filenames with extension.

Something like this:

| E | I |
| --- | --- |
| **Filename_A** | **Filename_B** |
| TSL_groups.mrk | pcbx_report.mrk |
| abcd.mrk | jhuo.mrk |

and so on...

I want to find if the files in column I (heading Filename_B) exist in column E (heading Filename_A).

If true, say TRUE in another column let's say column K.

Comment: Use the Vlookup Formula. Check the Excel help :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could try this

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(<single column I value>,<entire column E range>,1,FALSE)),FALSE, TRUE)
```

-or-

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(<single column I value>,<entire column E range>,1,FALSE)),"FALSE", "File found in row "   & MATCH(<single column I value>,<entire column E range>,0))
```

you could replace `<single column I value>` and `<entire column E range>` with named ranged. That'd probably be the easiest.

Just drag that formula all the way down the length of your I column in whatever column you want.

Answer (score 42):

You can use VLOOKUP, but this requires a wrapper function to return `True` or `False`. Not to mention it is (relatively) slow. Use COUNTIF or MATCH instead.

Fill down this formula in column K next to the existing values in column I (from `I1` to `I2691`):

```
=COUNTIF(<entire column E range>,<single column I value>)>0
=COUNTIF($E$1:$E$99504,$I1)>0
```

You can also use MATCH:

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(<single column I value>,<entire column E range>)))
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH($I1,$E$1:$E$99504,0)))
```

Comment: also +1. Note that as MATCH returns either a number or an error then rather than NOT with ISNA you can simply use ISNUMBER (or even COUNT which will return a 1/0 result)

Comment: @barryhoudini Good point, there are several different combinations of formulas that would work.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this. :) simple solution!

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(I1,E:E,0)),"TRUE","")
```